# How to solve linear system with sparse large matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have the following system that I need to solve. The matrix is large $n \times n$, where $n = Nz* Nr \approx 150000$ or larger.
The matrix always has the following form: Just 5 diagonals at $Nz, 1, 0, -1, -Nz$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
A & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & A & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & A & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
A & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & A & 0 & 0 & A & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & A \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & A & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & A & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A & A \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 0 & 0 & A & A \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_1 \\
\phi_2 \\
\phi_3 \\
\phi_4 \\
\phi_5 \\
\phi_6 \\
\phi_7 \\
\phi_8 \\
\phi_9 \\
\phi_{10} \\
\phi_{11} \\
\phi_{12} \\
\phi_{13} \\
\phi_{14} \\
\phi_{15} \\
\phi_{16} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
B \\
B \\
B \\
B \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
All $A$s and $B$s are different, I just wrote them like that for simplicity. Can anyone suggest an appropriate method I could read for this very specific case? My end goal is to implement this in C++.
I thought of doing it by gaussian elimination, but I hink it would require a lot of memory.

Comment: Looks like a banded matrix to me. Is that the case?

Comment: No, there are two diagonals at $Nz$ and $-Nz$ that are not part of the centred band.

Comment: Still looks banded to me. No one is saying that the band cannot contain zero diagonals.

Comment: Then yes, it is banded with lower and upper bandwidth ok $Nz$

Comment: Iterative methods are a standard approach to solving large sparse systems. You can look into GMRES, or CG if the matrix is symmetric positive definite.